# What mesoamerican culture used long, "pike-like" spears?

Tags: military, weapons, mexico, civilizations, mesoamerica

A while back, I read about some Mesoamerican tribe or culture that armed many of its warriors with extremely long spears, that either the Spanish invaders or the article I read itself compared to the European weapon called a pike.  However, I can't recall the name of the tribe that used this weapon, nor where I read about it.  I've tried every combination of search terms I could think of to find this information again, but I haven't had any luck, so I'm turning to this community.

In case it helps, I seem to recall that the tribe/culture in question was either a client state of the Aztecs at some point, or frequently warred with them.  Also, if memory serves, the spears they used had a shaft somewhere in the range of 15 to 20 feet long.  (That's roughly 4.5 to 6 meters for those of you using the metric system.)

Can anyone tell me what tribe/culture it was that used these weapons?

Answer (score 7):

Bernal Díaz del Castillo obliquely compared [spears of the Chinantec people](https://books.google.com/books?id=E9ii1kHEeu4C&lpg=PA331&ots=F3n_djzLPi&dq=cortes%20mexico%20spears%20-%22broken%20spears%22&hl=es&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q&f=false) to pikes (at least in translation -- I didn't check the Spanish original) and remarked that they were longer than the Castilian equivalent.

Several Mesoamerican groups used spears. Here are Aztec warriors wielding *[tepoztopilli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tepoztopilli)*:

[image: Aztec warriors from Codex Mendoza]